# GIF Images into 2D byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, image, gif, dct

I'm opening GIF image and with N parameter I decide which frames are the key frame and others are not. Then I want to split key frames into 8*8 block and perform DCT on them. My prolbem is that when I convert each key frame into byte array they are all diffrent sizes.

For example:

- Width/height:250/250
- 17frames
- 6key frames....first one and N=3 so each third one
- 11 other frames
- Key frame byte[] sizes: 19049, 19417,18828,18904,19572,18782

Now how can I split this equal into 2D array and how so that there is sucha diffrence. Am I missing something about GIF format?

```
Image[] key_frames;
Image[] other_frames;
void getFrames(Image originalImg)
{
    int N = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int size;
    int numberOfFrames = originalImg.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);
    if (N == 1)
        size = numberOfFrames / 2;
    else
        size = numberOfFrames / N + 1;

    key_frames = new Image[size];
    other_frames = new Image[numberOfFrames-size];

    int counter = 0,array_counter=0, array_counter_others=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++)
    {
        originalImg.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, i);
        if (i == 0 || counter == N-1)
        {
            key_frames[array_counter] = ((Image)originalImg.Clone());
            counter = 0;
            array_counter++;
            if (N == 1)
                counter--;
        }
        else
        {
            other_frames[array_counter_others]= ((Image)originalImg.Clone());
            counter++;
            array_counter_others++;
        }
    }
}

public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string file = "";
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    Image img = Image.FromFile(file);
    int width = img.Width;
    int height = img.Height; 
    pictureBox1.Width = width;
    pictureBox1.Height = height;
    pictureBox1.Image = img;

    getFrames(img);

    Dictionary<int, byte[]> byte_key_frames = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
    Dictionary<int, byte[]> byte_other_frames = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();

    int counter = 0;
    foreach(Image frame in key_frames)
    {
        byte_key_frames.Add(counter, imageToByteArray(key_frames[counter]));
        counter++;
    }
    counter = 0;
    foreach (Image frame in other_frames)
    {
        byte_other_frames.Add(counter, imageToByteArray(other_frames[counter]));
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gif is a compressed format. This means the size is related to the contents of the image; more clear space compresses better than lots of variation. The bytes you get are saved images, after all, not raw image RGB contents.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that the .Net framework somehow seems to consider animated gifs as 32bppARGB images, meaning that re-saving them as gif will cause them to use a standard palette, and will seriously decrease their quality. I have not found any method in c# to even retrieve the original palette of such animated gifs, so far. The only option may be to investigate the format and extract the bytes of each frame and load those as separate gif files, somehow.